# Touch each custom ListView item with calabash-android

Tags: bdd, calabash, calabash-android

So I try to touch an custom ListView item to see next View and then I want to move back but right now I'm not able to query any of my list item.

My gherkin code is:

```
Then I choose category:
        | Artystyczne |
        | Językowe  |
        | Komputery i robotyka  |
        | Korepetycje |
        | Medyczne  |
        | Praktyczno-techniczne |
        | Rozrywkowe  |
        | Rozwijające |
        | Sportowe  |
        | Taneczne  |
        | Pozostałe |
```

and in my step looks like:

```
Then(/^I choose category:$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  data = table.raw
  data.each do |i|
    #tap_mark i
    #tap_when_element_exists("* {text CONTAINS[c] '#{i}'}")
    touch(i)
    #TODO move back one View
  end
end
```

when I run test the error says:

```
Then I choose category:                       # features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:25
      | Artystyczne           |
      | JÄtzykowe              |
      | Komputery i robotyka  |
      | Korepetycje           |
      | Medyczne              |
      | Praktyczno-techniczne |
      | Rozrywkowe            |
      | RozwijajÄce           |
      | Sportowe              |
      | Taneczne              |
      | PozostaĹ'e             |
      Failed to perform gesture. java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String (RuntimeError)
      ./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:28:in `each'
      ./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:28:in `/^I choose category:$/'
      features\my_first.feature:11:in `Then I choose category:'
```

I've tried to do some debug in `calabash-android console` and funny thing is that `tap_mark "Artystyczne"` is working perfectly. So I assume that there is something wrong with my `Data Tables` but can't figure (or google) what. I would appreciate any help :)

Have a nice day :)

[Steps definitions](http://pastebin.com/Np9xAmtM)

[Features](http://pastebin.com/c0T1H7SZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Then(/^I choose category:$/) do |table|   
 data = table.raw
            data.each do |identifiers|
                identifiers.each do |identifier|
                    tap_when_element_exists("* {text CONTAINS[c] '#{identifier}'}")
                    sleep(1)
                end
            end
```

You got assoc array here u need 2 each loops ;)

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you have tried

```
tap_mark "Artystyczne"
```

However you posted that you step is

```
Then(/^I choose category:$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  data = table.raw
  data.each do |i|
    touch(i)
  end
end
```

You are using touch and that can not use a simple text to identify the item to touch. It needs a query.

Something in the style of

```
touch "ListView marked:'#{i}'"
```